# Joomla 3 add new tab to article manager

Tags: php, plugins, joomla, content-management-system, article

[image]

This is [Joomla 3.3](http://www.joomla.org/3/en).
I want to add a tab to article *add*/*edit*. Basically I want to let user to change the content themselves according to a predefined layout.

Is there any tutorial on this?

**EDIT**

I want to create a plugin/module/component for article form. Meaning to say that want to add additional info/meta to the article.

Answer (score 2):

You can add custom data to any of the core tables as described at [Adding Custom Fields to Core Components](http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_core_components_using_a_plugin)  (though #__content is slightly different).  I've outlined how to do it for #__content at [Joomla StackExchange](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2395/how-to-save-custom-fields-in-core-components).

Comment: The language file seems not loaded, it shows constant instead of the text. Do you have any working example?